# How to write contents of Document Object to String in NekoHTML?

Tags: java, html-parsing, transformer-model, neko

I am using NekoHTML to parse contents of some HTML file..

Everything goes okay except for extracting the contents of the Document Object to some string.

I've tried uses

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

But nothing appears returned.

Comment: Please define what 'writer' is. FileWriter can be used to write to a file and StringWriter to write to a string buffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem where in Oracle App server 10.3.1.4 http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com/2011/04/oracle-application-server-overrides.html

Answer (score 0):

Posible solution:

```
//this nekohtml  
DOMParser parser = new DOMParser();  
parser.parse(archivo);  


//this xerces  
OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(parser.getDocument());   
format.setIndenting(true);  

//print xml for console 
//XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(System.out, format); 

//save xml in string var 
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outputStream, format); 

//process
serializer.serialize(parser.getDocument()); 


String xmlText = outputStream.toString();  

System.out.println(xmlText); 

//to generate a file output use fileoutputstream instead of system.out 
//XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(new FileOutputStream(new File("book.xml")), format);
```

Url: http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#6.2

See ***e) Serialize DOM to FileOutputStream to generate the xml file "book.xml"*** .